# Skip "login.windows.net" and redirect to federated ADFS

Tags: single-page-application, claims-based-identity, azure-active-directory, adal, office365-apps

Any suggestion on how to skip the selection of login url (home realm?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.cloudidentity.com/blog/2014/11/17/skipping-the-home-realm-discovery-page-in-azure-ad/

> In OAuth2 and OpenId Connect you do so by passing the target domain in the  “domain_hint” parameter. 
>   In ADAL you can pass it via the following:

```
AuthenticationResult ar =
    ac.AcquireToken("https://developertenant.onmicrosoft.com/WebUXplusAPI",
                    "71aefb3b-9218-4dea-91f2-8b23ce93f387",
                    new Uri("http://any"), PromptBehavior.Always, 
                    UserIdentifier.AnyUser, "domain_hint=mydomain.com");
```

> In the OWIN middleware for OpenId Connect you can do the same in the RedirectToIdentityProvider notification:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
    {
        ClientId = clientId,
        Authority = authority,
        PostLogoutRedirectUri = postLogoutRedirectUri,
        Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications()
        {
            RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) => 
            {                                                        
                context.ProtocolMessage.DomainHint = "mydomain.com"; 
                return Task.FromResult(0); 
            }, 
        }
    });
```

> Finally, in WS-Fed you do the following:

```
app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
   new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
   {
      Notifications = new WsFederationAuthenticationNotifications
      {
         RedirectToIdentityProvider = (context) =>
         {
            context.ProtocolMessage.Whr = "mydomain.com";
            return Task.FromResult(0);
         }
      }
   }
}
```

So, if your are using ADAL js, just add to your ADAL init:

```
extraQueryParameter: 'domain_hint=yourCompany.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

This did not work properly for me. I found that if I wanted to skip the Home Realm Discovery page I had to use the Resource Explorer and do it directly in the authSettings.

[This article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/appserviceteam/2016/07/13/app-service-auth-and-aad-domain-hints/) almost had what I needed (see Default Login Parameters section).  However, [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-web/web-sites-dotnet-lob-application-azure-ad) explained enough for me to find what I need in the Resource Explorer (see step 13 which shows the proper path).

The main thing is to find the authSettings section and proper key. You don’t have to ADD the key in the Resource Explorer; you just need to add a domain_hint value. If you don’t see the key, you are in the wrong location. The proper location is: Subscription -> [your subscription name] -> ResourceGroups -> [name of the resource group] -> providers -> Microsoft.Web -> sites -> [name of your site] -> authsettings